# Facebook SDK iOS Login

Tags: iphone, facebook, sdk, authentication

Using the Facebook SDK for iOS, how does one figure out whether or not a user is already signed in so the app does not have to go through a login process?

Currently during the login process, I am saving the access token and expiration date to the user defaults and then reading those back out when I initialize a facebook object at the start of my application's run time.

But what happens if a user backgrounds the app, goes into Safari, changes to a different Facebook account or signs, then comes back into my own app. Shouldn't the Facebook app return that the stored session isn't valid anymore?  How would I figure this out?  Currently, my facebook object maintains that the session is valid, but unfortunately when I try to publish something,  I see nothing on the appropriate Facebook page.

Am I missing something here?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can `[facebook isSessionValid]` help?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the correct thing saving and restoring the facebook access token & expiration date. Any FB API that requires a valid token will fail with an error if you call it with an expired token. Handle the error and logout locally from FB then ask your user to login again.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to Facebook's login on an iPhone (SDK v3.0+), it ranks the System Level Login 1st, Facebook native iOS app 2nd, and mobile Safari Facebook login 3rd. But if the user logged into your app using mobile safari, backgrounded the app, logged into a different Facebook account using mobile safari, then returned to your app, the access token and session in your app will be valid until you log out of your iOS app. Typically you log out using this line:

```
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
```

Login is initiated by some variation of this line:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:
```

If you're using Facebook iOS SDK 3.2+, you can call the following to see if an authenticated Facebook session is open:

```
[[FBSession activeSession] isOpen]
```

Also, you don't have to save the access token or expiration date locally. You can access them with these calls:

```
[FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData.accessToken
[FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData.expirationDate
```

Here's a link to some relevant Facebook iOS docs:

[Facebook Login - iOS SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate)